# How to get storage location in Cordova/PhoneGap?

Tags: android, cordova, local-storage, storage

I wish to store some application specific data (images & sound) which are downloaded during runtime. The download part has works correctly (using `new FileTransfer();`) but currently the target storage path is still hardcoded (i.e. `file:///storage/emulated/0/myapp` on my Genymotion simulator)

I believe the storage path is different among different devices, isn't it? If so, how to get the root path of the storage folder? I am not really particular about whether the folder is private or shared among different applications.

*I have checked https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file/blob/master/doc/index.md, but not really sure how to use the API.

I am using the latest Phonegap (3.4.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can use `window.requestFileSystem` for this.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/LocalFileSystem

However, if you don't like the fact that it's effectively "dead" now use the FileSystem Cordova plugin instead.

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file/blob/master/doc/index.md

Comment: Unfortunately, from http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/: "In April 2014, it was announced on public-webapps that the Filesystem API spec should be considered dead. Other browsers have showed little interest in implementing it."

Comment: Then use the FileSystem plugin instead.
https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file/blob/master/doc/index.md